# Text editor value disappears in React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, editor, accordion

I am making a simple accordion and inside each accordion, there is a text editor.

**Accordion.js**

```
<div className="wrapper">
  {accordionData.map((item, index) => (
    <Accordion>
      <Heading>
        <div
          style={{ padding: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
          className="heading"
          onClick={() => toggleHandler(index)}
        >
          {toggleValue !== index ? `Expand` : `Shrink`}
        </div>
      </Heading>
      <Text>  {toggleValue === index && item.content && <EditorContainer />} </Text>
    </Accordion>
  ))}
</div>
```

Here accordion is made up of as a component. This line `{toggleValue === index && item.content && <EditorContainer />}`  is made to check the accordion clicked and then it loads the content and text editor accordingly.

**Complete working example:**

> **https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-dcqbo**

**Steps** to reproduce the issue:

-> Open the above link

-> There will be three accordion

-> Click on any of the accordion, that will change the text from **Expand** to **Shrink**

-> Now fill some random text inside the editor then click on the text **Shrink**

-> Again open the same accordion by clicking **Expand**

-> Now already entered value is missing

I doubt it happens because every time we expand/shrink, the text_editor.js component gets called and that has the state value like,

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
};
```

Here instead of EditorState.createEmpty(), Should I need to give any other thing?

**Requirement:**

How can I store the already entered value in the text editor. Even though user clicks expand/shrink, the entered text needs to be remain there in the editor.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have written nice code. Looks like when you expand/shrink the code the component re-renders. you need to maintain the text written in state.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma, Can you provide a working example as a solution? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the entered value is missing because you are unmounting the `EditorContainer` component when its shrinked — that when you expand it again it creates a new `editorState` which is empty.

2 Possible solutions I could think of.

1. Move `editorState` and `onEditorStateChange` to the Parent component and pass that to `EditorContainer`. This way, when we unmount the `EditorContainer` we won't lose the previous `editorState` because it's on the Parent.
2. We wrap our `EditorContainer` inside a `div` and we'll apply a `display` style when we toggle between shrink/expand. This way, we are only hiding the `EditorContainer` not unmounting so its `states` will retain.

I would choose to implement the 2nd solution because we only have to make changes to our `Accordion.js` file. In either ways, I would create a new component that would handle the current item. I call it `NormalAccordionItem`.

```js
const NormalAccordionItem = ({ data }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setShow((prev) => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <Accordion>
      <Heading>
        <div
          style={{ padding: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
          className="heading"
          onClick={toggle}
        >
          {show ? "Shrink" : "Expand"}
        </div>
      </Heading>
      <Text>
        <div style={{ display: show ? "block" : "none" }}> // notice this
          <EditorContainer />
        </div>
      </Text>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

Then on our `NormalAccordion` we'll use `NormalAccordionItem`.

```js
const NormalAccordion = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {accordionData.map((data) => (
        <NormalAccordionItem data={data} key={data.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

That's it, check the demo below.

**Edit** Updated demo to expand `NormalAccordionItem` one at a time.

[image: Edit React-accordion (forked)]

Comment: Again and again I can express only a big thanks bro.. You are amazing..

Comment: HI bro, Sorry for disturbing you again.. I need a big help from you.. PLease take a look at this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-8i8kh .. Here I need to include the text editor and other inputs (Company name, designation, start date and end date and the detail (text editor) ) .. I am facing issue that some of the property is not defined.. Could kindly humbly help me please..

Comment: You are well known for this scenario and hence I am seeking your help .. Please help me bro I am stuck with the entire things..

Comment: REquirement is I need to make the input controls for each section inside expand/collapse .. Previously we did it without expand/collapse but now it needs to be expand/collapse and hence I am facing a lot of issue one by one.. So consider my request and help me bro.. I can provide you more details if needed..

Comment: You are accessing `inputField` inside `NormalAccordionItem` yet you passed `data={inputField}` from the `EmploymentDetails`. You should use, `data.companyName`?

Comment: Thanks I have changed it to ```inputField``` as props name.. However now I have implemented entire accordion with expand/collapse here https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-m9z30 inside which all the input controls are there.. But here if I enter any date value then that doesn't gets reflected in JSON and the text editor value also not gets included in JSON format.. Could you figure me out what I am doing wrong.. If you help this I think I am almost done..

Comment: I think I am almost done https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-e990t .. Thanks for your valueable feedback..